# NotificationServicceListener doesn't work after upgrade to Android 13

Tags: android

I have an Android app that I had to upgrade to Android 13 from Android 10.  The NotificationServiceListener service code is designed to receive all posted and removed notifications and then filters the ones to be processed and ignore the others.

After the upgrade, the NotificationListenerService service component is no longer invoked, not even it's "onCreate" method.

I've searched extensively but I can find nothing that helps.

My AndroidManifest is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sygic.example.hello3dwiw">

    <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" / -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_IMAGES" / -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:maxSdkVersion="30"  android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30"  android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        tools:replace="icon, label, theme">

        <activity android:name="com.sygic.example.hello3dwiw.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.sygic.example.hello3dwiw.NotificationService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

</manifest>
```

The service Java code remains unchanged.

I can find no information on additional permissions or settings.

Has anyone encountered this or have any thoughts?

Regards,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

This behavior [change](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#declare) has occurred with Android 13.

Declare the permission

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

You must handle leave situations yourself. If the user does not allow it, you can design a special screen.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but it didn't cause notifications to be sent to my NotificationServiceLIstener.    Do I need any other manifest elements?